# Using backquote (backtick) in JavaScript will result in "can not read property 'style' of null '

Tags: javascript, html, css, pug

I am trying to generate a click event on dynamically generated html id using JavaScript.

I used backquote to register the click event, but I get
**`can not read property 'style' of null`**

If you check the rendered HTML, `${post_.id}` is normally output after the css id identifier, but the style registered by the event listener can not be read.

What mistakes have I made?

**index.pug**

```
...
head
      script.
      function click(id) => {
        let element = document.getElementById(id);
        if element.style.display == 'none' {
          element.style.display = 'block'
        }
        else {
          element.style.display = 'none'
        }
      }
...
body
...
      //- pug templates
      each post in posts

      //- not working
      a(onclick=`click(div_${post._id})`) update

      div(id=`div_${post._id}` style="display: none;)
```

Comment: I don't know Pug, but I guess it's putting the backtick literally into the element, not expanding it when processing the template.

Comment: I agree @Barmar.

Comment: However, in order to dynamically assign a css id identifier, post_.id, which is the id of the post stored in mongodb, is needed. Simply expressing it as ' " " ' will not accept post_.id.

Comment: Pug doesn't support this. But you can use some types of interpolation, a look at the documentation will make that clear pretty fast: https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html

Comment: I've tried it with "a(onclick='clickme(edit_form_#{post_.id})'", but the rendered HTML returns " a(onclick='clickme(edit_form_#{post_.id})' ".

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but there are several things wrong with the Pug: 1) the javascript under the script tag in the head needs to be indented another level. 2) attributes in pug need to be comma separated 3) the style attribute is missing a final quote